# Android drawable layer set color fails

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I am trying to change the color of a layer in my drawable programmatically, so the actual drawable xml file would not change, but just the current drawable that is used as an src in my `ImageView`.

The object I am working with is a 3 circles (3 oval shapes) nested inside each other (see `card_template.xml`) below.

I have the following code:

```
    LayerDrawable cardLayers = (LayerDrawable) keyCard.getDrawable();
    System.out.println("Number of layers (should be 3): "+ cardLayers.getNumberOfLayers());
    GradientDrawable layer1 = (GradientDrawable) (cardLayers.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.card_layer1));
    layer1.setColor(0);
```

I know I'm getting the correct drawable, because of the `System.out.println` value, but when I set the color of the layer in `layer1.setColor(0);`, the layer just disappears - the outer circle is not shown in the `keyCard` ImageView anymore.

Neither `layer1.setColorFilter(0, PorterDuff.Mode.___)` is not working in any mode, the layer either stays the same or disappears..

Why is this happening? I couldn't find my solution not in docs, and not in any question here or elsewhere.

Please help :)

Here is `card_template.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/card_layer1">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <size
            android:width="5dp"
            android:height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:id="@+id/card_layer2" android:top="2dp" android:left="2dp" android:right="2dp" android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ff0000"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <size
            android:width="5dp"
            android:height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@+id/card_layer3" android:top="4dp" android:left="4dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="4dp">
    <shape android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#ffffff"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        <size
            android:width="5dp"
            android:height="5dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [GradientDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html) documentation setColor takes ColorStateList.

Please go through [ColorStateList](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html) to learn more. try and give an appropriate colorstate object instead of 0.

Comment: This is not realted to the answer, since there is also a setColor with int argument... It should work as well, and that's what I want to use :)